# I'm trying to add a piece of formula to an existing formula but is not working. When I put a number into the strName variable it works

Tags: vba, excel-formula

```vba
Dim strName As String
strName = "+2*SUMIF('Lvl 51,54'!C32:C180;$C42;'Lvl 51,54'!D32:D180)"


ActiveCell.Formula = ActiveCell.Formula + strName
```

Comment: You need to use `.FormulaLocal` or change the formula separator to `,` from `;`.

Comment: OMG thank you. That was the issue